# Meu botão não funciona quando coloco o f:validateRegex

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Sem o f:validateRegex o botão funciona normalmente, mas após colocar o f:validateRegex para validar os dados do input, não funciona mais, alguém pode ajudar?

Segue o código em anexo, não consigo formatar ele aqui...

[image: Botão não executa, só limpa os campos]

Comment: Cole o código(e não a imagem), para ficar mais fácil de lhe ajudarmos.

Comment: Tentei colocar o código e não aparece, fica só dois asterisco.

Answer (score 0):

Seus inputs estão com o `id` duplicado:

```
<h:inputSecret id="passwordInput">
```

Abcs!

Comment: Mas o botão valida o passwordInput, como faço para ele validar os dois inputs?

Comment: cada um tem que tem um id próprio